# Order by a parameter with case-when

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

i have this procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spConsultaPorcentagem
    @usuario nvarchar(60) = NULL,
    @dataEmissao datetime,
    @dataSaida datetime,
    @ordem nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  NFI.ID_Produto, SUM(NFI.Quantidade) AS Quantidade, MIN(PS.Descricao) AS Nome, MAX(NFI.ValorUnitario) AS Valor,
        SUM(NFI.ValorTotal) AS ValorTotal, cast(SUM(NFI.ValorTotal)*100/SUM(SUM(NFI.ValorTotal)) OVER () AS decimal(10,3)) AS Porcentagem,
        SUM(SUM(NFI.ValorTotal)) OVER() AS ValorFinal

                           // INNER JOINS

    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @ordem = 'alfabetica' THEN Nome END,
        CASE WHEN @ordem = 'quantidade' THEN Quantidade END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @ordem = 'valor' THEN ValorTotal END DESC
END
```

but is returning invalid column name on `Nome` and Ambiguous column name on `ValorTotal`, Why ?

**EDIT 1**

I solved it by doing this

```
CASE WHEN @ordem = 'alfabetica' THEN MIN(PS.Descricao) END,
CASE WHEN @ordem = 'quantidade' THEN SUM(NFI.Quantidade) END DESC,
CASE WHEN @ordem = 'valor' THEN SUM(NFI.ValorTotal) END DESC
```

Comment: Qualify *all* columns references.  It is that simple.  Then you won't have problems with ambiguous column references.

Comment: Strange, I see no problem with the query. I assume you `GROUP BY NFI.ID_Produto`? In that case there is only one `Nome` and one `ValorTotal` (and one `Quantidade` for that matter) in the result. That should be no problem hence. You may be able to circumvent the issue by choosing names that don't equal your column names.